# Connecting SmartFusion board to a Mac or Linux

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port, usb, uart

I am currently trying to connect my smartfusion to my Mac computer.  I have hooked up an FTDI chip to the SmartFusion and connected it via USB to my computer.  I was under the impression that I could just open a file descriptor in the `/dev` directory and read and write to it to send messages.  Is this not the case?  I have tried going into the `/dev` directory but I cannot seem to be able to execute `cat` on either of the devices that have the string `usb` in them.  I get garbage when I execute `cat` on one of them and get nothing on the other.

I tried using screen with the following command

```
screen <name_with_usb in /dev> 9600
```

but that outputted garbage as well

I have also tried to write the following C++ program that uses the FTDI drivers to try and open a connection with the FTDI chip.  I installed these drivers using the command below

```
brew install libftdi
```

And this is the program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ftdi.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    struct ftdi_context ftdi;
    ftdi_init(&ftdi);
    if (ftdi_usb_open(&ftdi, 0x0403, 0x6001) < 0) {
        cerr << "Can't open FTDI device\n";
        return -1;
    }


    cout << "Hello World" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with the following command

```
g++ -std=c++14 -I /usr/local/Cellar/libftdi/1.2/include/libftdi1/ -L /usr/local/Cellar/libftdi/1.2/lib/ -l ftdi1 reader_test.cpp -o reader
```

*NOTE* I am constantly sending strings over UART to the FTDI chip that is connected to my laptop.

If someone has any suggestion that could be helpful I would be really grateful!  I require this as soon as possible!

Answer (score 0):

**for Linux**

run command 
--> lsusb --> to find the product and vendor id of newly connected chip

--> modprobe ftdi_sio --> this will load the driver

a new file will be generated called new_id under ftdi_sio folder , iam sure you can find it

just add product and vendor id in that file with a space in between 
e.g 1234 5678   where 1234 is product id and 5678 is vendor id